# Work out number of hours based on hours in working day

Tags: c#, .net, datetime

I'm trying to work out the number of days between two dates based on working a specified number of hours per day. I'm having trouble working out how many full and half days are in 1 day selected, e.g. if 1 day was selected on the calendar then this would actually be 1 whole day.

If 09:00 on day one was selected and say 13:00 on day 2 then this would be around 12 working hours and 1.5 days.

EDIT : Last and hopefully final update, this shows end result code to make the question more readable in future

still need to add bank holiday checking etc but its roughly there)

```
//Validate working day rules are available
                    List<DayOfWeek> lDaysValidated = new List<DayOfWeek>();
                    double dTotalDays = 0;

                    //loop though the  days between the two dates
                    for ( var day = dtStartDate; day <= dtEndTime; day = day.AddDays( ( 1 ) ) )
                    {
                        //Only perform validation if the day of week has not already been validated
                        if ( !lDaysValidated.Contains( day.DayOfWeek ) )
                        {
                            //Look for working day rules for the user
                            List<UserTimeRule> lWorkingDayRules = UserTimeRule.GetUserTimeRules(
                                this.CurrentHolidayRequest.RequestedByID,
                                day.DayOfWeek,
                                false,
                                Settings.Instance.CostingModule,
                                TimeRuleRecordTypeEnum.DayRule );

                            //If the user has no rules, check the defaults
                            if ( lWorkingDayRules.Count == 0 )
                            {
                                //Get default rules for the day of week
                                lWorkingDayRules = UserTimeRule.GetDefaultUserTimeRules(
                                    day.DayOfWeek );

                                //If there is still no day rule, show error message and return
                                if ( lWorkingDayRules.Count == 0 )
                                {
                                    //Show error message
                                    lblWorkingDaysError.Text =
                                        String.Format(
                                            "* The current user has no working day rules set up, and there is no default day rule for '{0}'",
                                            day.DayOfWeek );

                                    return;
                                }
                                else
                                {
                                    //Calculate the working days
                                    this.CalculateWorkingDays(
                                       ref dtStartDate,
                                        ref dtEndTime,
                                        day,
                                        lWorkingDayRules,
                                        ref dTotalDays
                                        );

                                    //Add the day of week to the list of already validated days
                                    lDaysValidated.Add( day.DayOfWeek );
                                }
                            }
                            else
                            {
                                //Calculate the working days
                                this.CalculateWorkingDays(
                                   ref dtStartDate,
                                   ref dtEndTime,
                                    day,
                                    lWorkingDayRules,
                                    ref dTotalDays
                                    );

                                //Add the day of week to the list of already validated days
                                lDaysValidated.Add( day.DayOfWeek );
                            }
                        }
                    }

                    #endregion Validate

                    #region Update Details

                    //Set the Dates
                    this.CurrentHolidayRequestLine.StartTime = dtStartDate;
                    this.CurrentHolidayRequestLine.EndTime = dtEndTime;

                    //Set the number of Days
                    this.CurrentHolidayRequestLine.Days = Convert.ToDecimal( dTotalDays );
```

And the method to calulate the total days:

```
/// <summary>
        /// Calculates the number of working days for a specified day
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="dtHolidayStartTime">The start time of the holiday request</param>
        /// <param name="dtHolidayEndTime">The end time of the holiday request</param>
        /// <param name="dtCurrentDay">The current day being evaluated</param>
        /// <param name="lWorkingDayRules">The current set of working day rules</param>
        /// <param name="dTotalDays">A reference to the total days on the request</param>
        [VersionChange( "7.3.88.271", "10/04/2011", "Method added to calculate No days on a request" )]
        private void CalculateWorkingDays( ref DateTime dtHolidayStartTime, ref DateTime dtHolidayEndTime, DateTime dtCurrentDay, List<UserTimeRule> lWorkingDayRules, ref double dTotalDays )
        {
            try
            {
                //Check whether Holiday start time is before the start time of the working day
                if ( dtHolidayStartTime.TimeOfDay < lWorkingDayRules[ 0 ].StartTime.TimeOfDay )
                {
                    dtHolidayStartTime = new DateTime(
                        dtHolidayStartTime.Year,
                        dtHolidayStartTime.Month,
                        dtHolidayStartTime.Day,
                        lWorkingDayRules[ 0 ].StartTime.Hour,
                        lWorkingDayRules[ 0 ].StartTime.Minute,
                        lWorkingDayRules[ 0 ].StartTime.Minute );
                }
                //Check whether the holiday end time is after the end time of a nomal working day
                if ( dtHolidayEndTime.TimeOfDay > lWorkingDayRules[ 0 ].EndTime.TimeOfDay )
                {
                    dtHolidayEndTime = new DateTime(
                        dtHolidayEndTime.Year,
                        dtHolidayEndTime.Month,
                        dtHolidayEndTime.Day,
                        lWorkingDayRules[ 0 ].EndTime.Hour,
                        lWorkingDayRules[ 0 ].EndTime.Minute,
                        lWorkingDayRules[ 0 ].EndTime.Minute );
                }
                //Check whether the holiday end time is after lunch time, but before the end of the day
                if ( dtHolidayEndTime.TimeOfDay > lWorkingDayRules[ 0 ].LunchEndTime.TimeOfDay
                    && dtHolidayEndTime.TimeOfDay < lWorkingDayRules[ 0 ].EndTime.TimeOfDay )
                {
                    dtHolidayEndTime = new DateTime(
                        dtHolidayEndTime.Year,
                        dtHolidayEndTime.Month,
                        dtHolidayEndTime.Day,
                        lWorkingDayRules[ 0 ].LunchEndTime.Hour,
                        lWorkingDayRules[ 0 ].LunchEndTime.Minute,
                        lWorkingDayRules[ 0 ].LunchEndTime.Minute );
                }

                //Create a date time object for the end current working day
                DateTime dtWorkingDayEndTime = new DateTime(
                    dtCurrentDay.Year,
                    dtCurrentDay.Month,
                    dtCurrentDay.Day,
                    lWorkingDayRules[ 0 ].EndTime.Hour,
                    lWorkingDayRules[ 0 ].EndTime.Minute,
                    lWorkingDayRules[ 0 ].EndTime.Second );

                //Create a date time object for the end of lunch
                DateTime dtWorkingDayLunchTime = new DateTime(
                    dtCurrentDay.Year,
                    dtCurrentDay.Month,
                    dtCurrentDay.Day,
                    lWorkingDayRules[ 0 ].LunchEndTime.Hour,
                    lWorkingDayRules[ 0 ].LunchEndTime.Minute,
                    lWorkingDayRules[ 0 ].LunchEndTime.Second );

                //Create a date time object for the start of the current day
                DateTime dtWorkingDayStartTime = new DateTime(
                    dtCurrentDay.Year,
                    dtCurrentDay.Month,
                    dtCurrentDay.Day,
                    lWorkingDayRules[ 0 ].StartTime.Hour,
                    lWorkingDayRules[ 0 ].StartTime.Minute,
                    lWorkingDayRules[ 0 ].StartTime.Second );

                //Check whether to add the first half of the day
                if ( dtHolidayEndTime >= dtWorkingDayLunchTime )
                {
                    dTotalDays += 0.5f;
                }

                //Check whether to add the second half of the day
                if ( dtHolidayEndTime >= dtWorkingDayEndTime )
                {
                    dTotalDays += 0.5f;
                }
            }
            catch ( Exception )
            {
                throw;
            }
        }
```

Comment: Don't forget to account for daylight saving.

Comment: I've written a library that can perform this kind of calculation very easily.  It is in production use at one client 24/7 for over a year now for a variety of complex global calendar calculations.  If you're interested in a licensed product, let me know.  (I don't have a website for it)

Comment: @uosɐſ: I don't think you're responding his answer or helping him with his problem...

Comment: @Marco - It is if he might consider a packaged solution.  People offer jQuery, Telerik, etc where appropriate.  He may not be interested but that's why I didn't post it as an answer.

Comment: break up your code in multiple methods to make it more readable.

Comment: @ jgauffin - I have removed previous code extracts and added the latest version of code to the question to make it more understandable

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this. This code is not written with VS, so it could be not perfect... use only logic inside of it.

```
int htot = 0, dtot = 0;
while (date2>date1) {
  int h1 = date1.Hour < work_start ? work_start : date1.Hour;
  int h2 = date1.Hour > work_end ? work_end : date1.Hour;
  htot += (h2-h1);
  dtot++;
  date1 = date1.AddDays(1);
}
```

Comment: @Marco - thanks for your response, I have attempted something like your suggestion but I dont think I have implemented it correctly or have misunderstood, I have edited my question with the updated section of code.

Comment: I took out the *days as this was causing a problem if just 1 day between tweo dates was selected ( was coming out at zero at the decimal value was less that 1) Trouble now is //Get the total working days by dividing the total hours on claim by the total hours for the specified working days                double dTotalWorkingDays = dTotalHoursOnClaim / dHoursInWorkingDays; always comes out at 1.0

Comment: @WraitNath: my idea was to calc total number of integer days (here is why days is declared and converted to int) so if date2 is the day after day1, days should be 0 or 1 depending if hour1 is greater than hour2. I gonna check...

Comment: @Marco - Thanks, i just want to make sure that only the time selected in the date range falls between the time returned from my Day Rules. eg I have a day rule for Monday that starts at 09:00 and ends in 17:30. So if a user selected 08:00 to 18:00 on monday the day rule would be looked up, and only the hours from 0900 to 1730 are used thus returning 8.5 hours. Then the 8.5 would be converted to total working days, in which case would be 1

Comment: @WraitNath: ok, another try. I cant' write code now, but try this. For each day between date1 and date2, you must check these things: if start_hour is less than work_starting_hour then start_hour=work_starting_hour; if end_hour is greater than work_end_hour then end_hour=work_end_hour. So for each day you can sum total_hours and increment total_days.
I try with code without using VS, so forgive some mistake and use only "logic".

Comment: @WraitNath: note that my code uses only hours, but probably you should check minutes too...

Comment: @Marco - no I have not solved it yet, needed to take a break yesterday after mind melt. Im going to have a chat in our development meeting this morning to see if any other ideas come up. Ill update the code to what I have so far after I have had another look at it.

Comment: @WraithNath: the code I posted and edited wasn't right for you?

Comment: @Marco - Sorry, just realised it had changed, Ill give it a go as soon as I can

Comment: @WraithNath: remeber, as I told you in a previous comment, I worked only with hours, but take the logic and use it with minutes too...

Comment: @ Marco - I have added the code for what I have ended up with that seems to work to my question at the bottom. Ill mark your response as answer, and your helpful comments. Good luck on SO

Comment: @WraithNath: glad to help you, glad your app is working now :)